# Snackbar action text color not changing

Tags: android, colors, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

I want to change the action text color for my snackbar, but it is not working for some reason.

I use the following code to display a snackbar:

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root), "text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setActionTextColor(R.color.yellow).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The argument of `setActionTextColor` is the `int` that represents the color, not the resource ID.

Instead of this:

```
.setActionTextColor(R.color.yellow)
```

try:

```
.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
```

If you want to use resources anyway, try:

```
.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name));
```

Note: To use ContextCompat, I assume you have included Support library to your `build.gradle` file (It is optional if you have already appcompat (v7) library too).

Comment: snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)); Worked for me....!

Comment: This only works if the the OP's "definition" of yellow is the same as the system.

Comment: About the getColor being deprecated, don't use @SuppressWarning but instead ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.youColor)

Comment: You are assigning a color resource reference to the Snackbar (@ColorRes), but if you look at the method #setActionTextColor is requesting a @ColorInt Integer which basically asks a hexadecimal repesentation of a color directly.

Answer (score 28):

Use

```
.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red))
```

instead of just

```
.setActionTextColor(R.color.red)
```

Comment: `getColor(int)` is deprecated use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

None of above answers helped me.
I found this solution, and it works by changing manually the TextView's text color

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(v, "Snackbar message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
snack.show();
```

Comment: If anyone wants to use the same technique for changing the action button just add something like `TextView action = view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);      action.setTextColor(view.getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change action button text color..

```
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

If you want to change action button background color..

```
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
Button button=
(Button) sbView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action);
button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Permission required!", 3000 /*Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE*/);
 snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // perform any action when the button on the snackbar is clicked
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
 snackbar.setBackgroundTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));      // set the background tint color for the snackbar
 snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_500)); // set the action button text color
 snackbar.show();
```