# Change the background color of action button in snackbar

Tags: android, background-color, android-styles, material-components-android, android-snackbar

how can I change the background color of action button in snackbar or make it dissapear (grey background)?

[image]

i use this code:

```
        Snackbar mysnack = Snackbar.make(main_layout, getResources().getString(R.string.snack_1), 5000);
            View view = mysnack.getView();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_light));
            mysnack.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_light));
            mysnack.setAction("RATE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.snack_url));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValue, true);
            final int color = typedValue.data;
            mysnack.getView().setBackgroundColor(color);
            mysnack.show();
```

and my question is not duplicate. I ask for BACKGROUND color and not the text color. First we read, then we understand, then we think and then we decide to write that someone's question is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snackbar action text color not changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116774/snackbar-action-text-color-not-changing)

Comment: Can you please add code ?

Comment: you can try making a custom snackbar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/4344258

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout try this out

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Found out it can be a bug of new Material theme.
Main theme of my application is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

If I change it to AppCompat snack button's gray background dissapears. Eventually I found that it was because of the bug.

My solution was (I needed Material theme and can not simply change it to AppCompat):
Found button id for the snack. It is "@id/snackbar_action":

```
val snackButton: Button = yourSnackbar.getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action)
```

and then changed it background to null:

```
snackButton.setBackground(null)
```

Comment: nice solution 

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet may help you out:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                    coordinatorLayout,
                    "Snackbar: floatingActionButton1 (normal) clicked",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

> for Reference [Click Here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/08/set-text-and-background-color-of.html)

Answer (score 1):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`snackbarButtonStyle`** attribute in your app theme.
Something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Style to use for action button within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton.Snackbar</item>
</style>


<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton.Snackbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For Xamarin you can try this one**

```
 snackbar.View.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#32CD32"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change action button background color..

```
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
Button button=
(Button) sbView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_action);
button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

If you want to change action button text color..

```
snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```